# Conditional probability about picking cards of a deck

Tags: probability

> Pick cards of an ordinary deck of 52, one by one and show the cards
> and stop once the first ace appears. If the first ace appears, what is
> the probability that the card following the first ace is a two of
> clubs?

### Attempt

Let $A=$ event that the first ace appears at 20th card and let $B$ be event that card after ace is the two of clubs. I want to find $P(B\mid A)$
we have

\begin{align*}
P(B \mid A) &= \dfrac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)} \\
       &= \dfrac{P(A\mid B)P(B)}{P(A)} \\
       &= \dfrac{P(A \mid B)P(B)}{P(A\mid B)P(B) + P(A\mid B^c)P(B^c)}
\end{align*}

Now, here is where I get stuck. Because as $P(A\mid B)$ reads: if $B$ has already occured, how would this affect the event $A$? does this mean that $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are indenpendent? but, then $P(B|A) = P(B) = \frac{1}{52-20} = \frac{1}{32}$. what am I doing wrong here?

### update:

Let's rename the events a little bit. Let $A$ be the event just as before and call $B$ the event that the card after the 20th, that is the one after  ace, is the 2 of clubs. Also, call $C$ the event that the 2 of clubs occur before the ace, that is, before the 20th card. We want to find $P(B \mid A)$. We have

\begin{align*}
P(B \mid A) &= \dfrac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)} \\
       &= \dfrac{ P(B \cap A \cap C) + P(A \cap A \cap C^c ) }{P(A)}\\
&= \dfrac{P(B \mid A \cap C) P(A \cap C) + P(B \mid A \cap C^c) P(A \cap C^c)}{P(A)} \\
&= \dfrac{P(B \mid A \cap C) P(A \mid C)P(A) + P(B \mid A \cap C^c) P(A \mid C^c) P(A)}{P(A)} \\
&=P(B \mid A \cap C) P(A \mid C) + P(B \mid A \cap C^c) P(A \mid C^c)\\
&= 0 \cdot \frac{1}{52} + \frac{1}{52-20} \cdot \left( 1 - P(C) \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: "event that the first ace appears at 20th card" Why the 20th card?? Did you forget something in the problem statement?

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2490988/probability-is-the-next-card-the-ace-of-spades-or-heart-two/2491267#2491267

Comment: Still after the update, my question is not answer. In the phrase " If the first ace appears, what ..." , I guess a "in the 20th" position is missed before the "what"? If not, then the phrase ("if the first ace appears")  make little sense, and neither does your observation : "event that the card after the 20th, _that is the one after ace_, is the 2 of clubs."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistakes include at least the following three:

1) Conditional probability has nothing to do with time. It deals with probabilities restricted to a certain part of the probability space. In subjective terms, it deals with how the probabilities you assign to events change if you obtain information. The information may be about a later event, and this may affect probabilities assigned to earlier events. If I draw first one card and then a second card and then tell you that the second card is an ace, that affects the probability you assign to the event of the first card being an ace.

2) The setup of your events is slightly ambiguous. By “let B be event that the card after the ace is the two of clubs”, do you mean that the card after the first ace is the two of clubs, no matter when you draw the first ace; or do you mean that the $21^{st}$ card is the two of clubs? These two interpretations are only equivalent if event $A$ occurs.

3) You're overthinking this. Imagine shuffling the deck without the two of clubs, then inserting the two of clubs at a uniformly random position. There are $52$ possible positions, and only one of them is behind the first ace, so the probability that the two of clubs ends up behind the first ace is $\frac1{52}$.

By the way, this gives you a nice way to calculate the probability that another ace comes right after the first ace: We could have considered any of the $48$ non-ace cards instead of the two of clubs, so the probability that a non-ace comes after the first ace is $\frac{48}{52}$, so the probability that an ace comes after the first ace is $\frac4{52}=\frac1{13}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have updated my question with the revised attempt. Am I doing better now? Im stuck at the end trying to find $P(C)$. Isn't is just $\frac{1}{52}$ ?

Comment: @JimmySabater: To my mind, the definitions of the events are even less clear now. You write "after the $20^{th}$, that is the one after ace" -- but as I said, those two definitions are only equivalent if $A$ occurs. That's fine as long as everything is conditioned on $A$, as on the left-hand side of the equation, but on the right-hand side you condition on other events (e.g. $C$), and then you have to decide which of the two definitions, which are inequivalent if $A$ doesn't occur, you want to use.

Comment: Why is the probability for the auxiliary problem 4/52 instead of 3/52 if there are only 3 aces left after the first is placed?

Comment: @user107224: You can't go about it that way because all the aces are behind the first ace, so it's $\frac3N$, where $N$ is the number of cards after the first ace, which is itself a random variable, so you'd have to calculate $\sum_{n=3}^{51}\mathsf P(A\mid N=n)\mathsf P(N=n)=\sum_{n=3}^{51}\frac3N\mathsf P(N=n)$, which is quite a complicated calculation -- that's why I like the fact that we can get the result in this very simple but slightly roundabout way :-)